# Matrix equation with several X

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Solving matrix equation 
$A^2X-B^T = 3X$ (to find X), I'm trying to do next thing:

$A^2X-B^T = 3X$
$A^2X-3X = B^T$
$(A^2-3)X = B^T$

Can we do it in that way and, if yes, what should we do with $(A^2 - 3)$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The equation $(A^2-3)X = B^T$ is equivalent to $X^T\left((A^T)^2-3I \right) = B$. Then you have to make a discussion on the content of the kernel of $B$. For example, if $v$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $\sqrt{3}$ of $A^T$, you have to have $v \in \ker A^T$. If not the equation has no solution... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$X = (A^2-3I)^{-1}B^T$$
If we assume that this matrix is invertible. Even if it is not, you may still be in the case that you have an underdetermined system, then you simply have infinitely many solutions. In the case where you have an overdetermined system you can use least squares.

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understood it in a right way, instead of 3, we use identity matrix multiplied by 3?

Comment: Yes a matrix with 3 on the diagonal.

Comment: @Sergey Malinov You can accept it as an answer if you don't need anymore clarifications on it.

Comment: I know, thank you for reminding, but I can not do it yet. In couple of minutes the system will let me do it